# Simulate select click on option in DropDown List

Tags: javascript

I have this list i would like to select 3th option or the option with value "ASD"

i tried this `document.querySelector(' #edit-activity-domain option:nth-child(4)').click();` 
or this `$('#edit-activity-domain').find('option:nth-child(3').prop('selected',true).trigger('change');`

```html
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-activity-domain" id="edit-activity-domain" name="activity-domain-id" class="form-select required select2-hidden-accessible" required="required" aria-required="true" style="" data-select2-id="edit-activity-domain" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="*" selected="true" data-select2-id="7">Votre domaine d'activité</option>
<option value="APT" data-select2-id="13">Accompagnement personnel et Thérapie</option>
<option value="ACE" data-select2-id="14">Artisans, Commerçants et e-Commerçants de détail</option><option value="ASD" data-select2-id="15">Associations et Syndicats</option>
<option value="OTS" data-select2-id="16">Autres services à la personne</option><option value="BIE" data-select2-id="17">Bien-Etre</option>
<option value="BET" data-select2-id="18">Bureaux d'études techniques</option>
</select>
```

```
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `getElementsByClassName`, here I added a new class to your dropdown list `selector`

```
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-activity-domain" id="edit-activity-domain" name="activity-domain-id" class="form-select required select2-hidden-accessible selector" required="required" aria-required="true" style="" data-select2-id="edit-activity-domain" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="*" selected="true" data-select2-id="7">Votre domaine d'activité</option>
<option value="APT" data-select2-id="13">Accompagnement personnel et Thérapie</option>
<option value="ACE" data-select2-id="14">Artisans, Commerçants et e-Commerçants de détail</option><option value="ASD" data-select2-id="15">Associations et Syndicats</option>
<option value="OTS" data-select2-id="16">Autres services à la personne</option><option value="BIE" data-select2-id="17">Bien-Etre</option>
<option value="BET" data-select2-id="18">Bureaux d'études techniques</option>
</select>
```

Then use `getElementsByClassName()` with index 0 because this returns an array like object and you only have 1 element with this class and then just select the index of the option you want to select

```
document.getElementsByClassName("selector")[0].selectedIndex = 2
```

you can also get elementbyid if you don't want to use the class

```
document.getElementById("edit-activity-domain").selectedIndex = 2
```

or if you want to use jquery using class

```
$("select.selector").val("ACE");
```

or jquery using id

```
$("#edit-activity-domain").val("ACE");
```

Comment: i can't edit the code, it's not my website

Comment: @ibibi what do you mean? you can't add a new class to your dropdown list? you can still use the class your element is already using and it will still work `$(".select2-hidden-accessible").val("ACE");` same result

Comment: yes i can't add new class, i can only use what's existing. 
and if i use "$(".select2-hidden-accessible").val("ACE");"
i got this error : 
"TypeError: $ is not a function. (In '$(".select2-hidden-accessible")', '$' is undefined)"

Comment: thats probably because you aren't using jquery, try using `document.getElementById("edit-activity-domain").selectedIndex = 2` instead

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hygcrx3m/

Comment: @ibibi as I said, you aren't using jquery, thats why is not working for you, here I fixed your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kenpy/azoxur4q/

Comment: i got this as result : "2 = $7"  but not selecting

Comment: https://ibb.co/c1ZrPX7

Comment: check the screenshot i put it in the console as it is, "$(".select2-hidden-accessible").val("ACE");"

Comment: that means you are not using jquery library, so avoid that solution then and just use pure js solution `document.getElementById("edit-activity-domain").selectedIndex = 2`

Comment: tinyurl.com/87jt34a3
i tried on the website doesn't work :s

Comment: website has several errors, that might be part of the reason

Comment: yes but can't do anything with that >< thank you for your help Chris !

Comment: allright, sorry I wasn't much help, no idea why is not working cuz it's working fine for me and it works in the jsfiddle

Comment: you tried and i really appreciate ! have a nice evening :) and thank you very much Chris !